# Unable to fetch kubeconfig from Charmed k8s

Tags: charmed-kubernetes

I installed juju on Azure VM by following this instruction.

https://juju.is/docs/juju/get-started-with-juju

Then I followed this instruction to deploy charmed k8s and looks like it was deployed successfully.
https://ubuntu.com/kubernetes/docs/operations

When I try to fetch the config from the cluster, the kubeconfig file is not found in there. When I run this command, the config file contains 'config: no such file of directory'.

juju ssh kubernetes-control-plane/leader -- cat config > ~/.kube/config

I accessed the leader node via SSH but can't find the config file there. By default, it should be located in ~/.kube/config but there's no such directory or file. Can anyone unblock this issue?

Thanks,
Masashi

Comment: What is the response you get when running the `sudo snap install kubectl --classic` command?